# Selecting Top 2 Values Using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ali |
| 2 | jack |
| 3 | rex |
| 4 | henry |
| 5 | clark |

i have this table. I need select top 2 values without knowing Which id belongs to which name.

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | henry |
| 5 | clark |

Comment: how top 2 are 4 and 5? doesn't make sense... you mean bottom 2?

Comment: highest two ids are 4 and 5

Comment: well... `top 2` means first and second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want `order by` and `limit`?

```
select t.*
from t
order by id desc
limit 2;
```

Comment: how to can I select ids are 3 and 4 using this method?

Comment: @bahoz99 now you are asking about totally differnt thing, start another question for that and accept this one as a valid answer